# Can I get links to Comments?

Tags: support, comments

At present, I can get specific links to Questions and Answers by **`share`** Option.  But for Comments only **`^`** and **`⚑`** are available

**Sometimes comments contain Great Information and is very much help full**. And It becomes necessary to have a link to specify a particular comment.

Comment: > Sometimes comments contain Great Information and is very much help full Surely it's better to just add the information from a comment into the answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you hover over the timestamp of a comment [it becomes a link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728459/tenda-w311m-usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-recongnized-ubuntu-14-04#comment1083812_728459). Share that URL.

[image]